Looking for movie: Person observes another's lifestyle and habits in the living room
I've been looking for this movie all day long but I cant find it.  I watched it in an independent theatre.
Plot: A Person has to observe the lifestyle and habits of some random person from morning to evening. At night he lives outside the house in a trailer. I believe it was somewhere in Scandinavia.
He observes an old guy, who talks sparely and only watches the observer. The observer always sits up on his observer chair. Later in that movie they start to socially interact with each other. It has something to do with the idea of Ikea observing people to make furniture especially for their needs.

@jonsca - I'm guessing he meant "sparely" (rarely)

I think it's Kitchen Stories:

In post war Sweden it was discovered that every year, an average housewife walks the equivalent number of miles as the distance between Stockholm and Congo, while preparing her family meals. 
So the Home Research Institute sent out eighteen observers to a rural district of Norway to map out the kitchen routines of single men. 
The researchers were on twenty-four-hour call, and sat in special strategically placed chairs in each kitchen.  

